# Acts_as_list works perfectly in development but fails in Heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed Ryan Bates's nice tutorial on making sortable list elements and was able to duplicate it to row elements in a table. I used acts_as_list (0.3.0) in development in order to create a "position" for newly created objects, in my case pages.

I ran the migration and can confirm that the field is created as an integer in my model (both environments).

Weird thing is, after I deply to Heroku and create a new page object I get:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms
NoMethodError (undefined method `position' for #<Page:0x007f450cdf79d0>):
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:37:in `create'
```

I simply added the "acts_as_list" line to my model. Is there something I'm missing? This works great in development and I'm using PostgreSQL in both environments.

Comment: Did you run the migration on heroku too?

Comment: I think I was getting tired ...

Anyways, in development mode I hadn't made my position attribute accessible but it worked fine. As soon as I made it accessible it also works fine on Heruko. My bad, silly mistake...

Comment: For me works fine in dev but in production it fails 'acts_as_list not found' :/